# SLD supports <Displacement>?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am trying to give style to a vector point layer published on `GeoServer` and I can notice the displacement command is not working. (Displacement inside PointSymbolizer Graphic)

Do you know it could be any problem in the SLD file? or it could be `GeoServer`?

Comment: It would be much more easy to answer if you could share the whole SLD file.

Comment: By looking at the SLD 1.0.0 schema http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd it looks like displacement is not supposed to be used in that place. It is meant for labels. I have not checked other SLD versions.

Comment: I am working with sld 1.0.0. If I change the version to 1.1.0 openlayers 2.13.1 doesn't work and gives me this error: "Uncaught Can't find a SLD parser for version 1.1.0". What could I do? THanks for the comment!

Comment: And if I publish the layer with that style 1.1.0 in Geoserver 2.6 it doesn't show the displacement either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLD 1.0.0 specification can be downloaded from https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=1188

Read below what is written about the Graphic. In short, Displacement does not work because it is not supported for Graphic.

```
A Graphic is a “graphic symbol” with an inherent shape, color(s), and possibly size. A
“graphic” can be very informally defined as “a little picture” and can be of either a raster
or vector-graphic source type. The term “graphic” is used since the term “symbol” is
similar to “symbolizer” which is used in a different context in SLD. The high-level
definition of a Graphic element is:
<xs:element name="Graphic">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element ref="sld:ExternalGraphic"/>
<xs:element ref="sld:Mark"/>
</xs:choice>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element ref="sld:Opacity" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element ref="sld:Size" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element ref="sld:Rotation" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="ExternalGraphic">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element ref="sld:OnlineResource"/>
<xs:element ref="sld:Format"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Format" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Opacity" type="sld:ParameterValueType"/>
<xs:element name="Size" type="sld:ParameterValueType"/>
<xs:element name="Rotation" type="sld:ParameterValueType"/>
```